# как сменить значок на панели и сверху окна IE, вызванного через VBS

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

Вызывая IE окно используя VBS с помощью
`Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`
Отображаются иконки IE(см.фото), как-то можно в скрипте их изменить?
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: А если favicon?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, пробовал, но как? 
просто в тело добавить <head><link rel='shortcut icon' href='vbsa.kl.com.ua/favicon.ico'></head> - не помогает, к сожалению

Comment: Ты протокол не указал. И ещё значение rel проверь - там есть варианты.

Comment: Извините? не понял немного, о чем Вы?

Comment: Http который? все-равно не работает

Comment: Ну тогда не знаю.